# MySQL Grouping total

Tags: mysql, sql, grouping

I just know the very basics of SQL. I have a database that shows when a person entered an office and when he left.

e.g

```
Name     Enter                    Exit
Jack     2014-01-01 01:00:00     2014-01-01 02:00:00
Sam      2014-01-01 02:00:00     2014-01-01 03:00:00
Jane     2014-01-01 02:00:00     2014-01-01 03:00:00
Judy     2014-01-01 03:00:00     2014-01-01 04:00:00
```

What I am trying to do is find out the total number of users that were in the office on an hourly basis, grouped by hours, and maybe grouped by date too, so my result should look like

```
date           hour   Occupancy
2014-01-01     1       1
2014-01-01     2       3
2014-01-01     3       3
2014-01-01     4       1
```

****EDIT

I can set the database to only collect hours and discard the minutes, however a person can come in and leave two days after too. So I am looking for something that is not only an hour apart entry and exit.

Comment: Try setting up your test case on http://sqlfiddle.com/ then show your attempts and share the result back here.

Comment: You will need to use WHILE LOOP (EnterValue <= ExitValue) SELECT statements getting your date,hour,count and then incrementing the time + INTERVAL 1 HOUR ... would be a good logical start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated answer:**

Okay, I adjusted your sample data to reflect the cases where Enter and Exit date are not on the same day and Enter and exit times differ in more than one hour.

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (`Name` varchar(4), `Enter` datetime, `Exit` datetime)
;

INSERT INTO t
    (`Name`, `Enter`, `Exit`)
VALUES
    ('Jack', '2014-01-01 01:00:00', '2014-01-01 02:00:00'),
    ('Sam', '2014-01-01 02:00:00', '2014-01-01 05:00:00'),
    ('Jane', '2014-01-01 02:00:00', '2014-01-01 03:00:00'),
    ('Judy', '2014-01-01 03:00:00', '2014-01-03 04:00:00')
;
```

To keep things easy I then created a table containing the date range covering our sample data.

```
drop table if exists n;
create table n(a int auto_increment primary key, b datetime);
insert into n (a) values(null), (null);

insert into n (a)
select null from n n1, n n2, n n3, n n4, n n5, n n6;
```

This quick hack inserted 66 numbers into our table. Next I generate the dates covering the sample data.

```
update n 
set b = '2014-01-01 00:00:00' + interval a hour;
```

Now that we have datetime values for every full hour between `2014-01-01 00:00:00` and `2014-01-03 18:00:00` we can use this table to simply join to it.

```
select date(n.b), hour(n.b), count(*)
from
t inner join n on n.b between t.Enter and t.Exit
group by 1, 2
```

This way we get a record for every full hour between the Enter and Exit time. And the result is:

```
|       DATE | HOUR | COUNT(*) |
|------------|------|----------|
| 2014-01-01 |    1 |        1 |
| 2014-01-01 |    2 |        3 |
| 2014-01-01 |    3 |        3 |
| 2014-01-01 |    4 |        2 |
| 2014-01-01 |    5 |        2 |
| 2014-01-01 |    6 |        1 |
| 2014-01-01 |    7 |        1 |
| 2014-01-01 |    8 |        1 |
| 2014-01-01 |    9 |        1 |
| 2014-01-01 |   10 |        1 |
| 2014-01-01 |   11 |        1 |
| 2014-01-01 |   12 |        1 |
| 2014-01-01 |   13 |        1 |
| 2014-01-01 |   14 |        1 |
| 2014-01-01 |   15 |        1 |
| 2014-01-01 |   16 |        1 |
| 2014-01-01 |   17 |        1 |
| 2014-01-01 |   18 |        1 |
| 2014-01-01 |   19 |        1 |
| 2014-01-01 |   20 |        1 |
| 2014-01-01 |   21 |        1 |
| 2014-01-01 |   22 |        1 |
| 2014-01-01 |   23 |        1 |
| 2014-01-02 |    0 |        1 |
| 2014-01-02 |    1 |        1 |
| 2014-01-02 |    2 |        1 |
| 2014-01-02 |    3 |        1 |
| 2014-01-02 |    4 |        1 |
| 2014-01-02 |    5 |        1 |
| 2014-01-02 |    6 |        1 |
| 2014-01-02 |    7 |        1 |
| 2014-01-02 |    8 |        1 |
| 2014-01-02 |    9 |        1 |
| 2014-01-02 |   10 |        1 |
| 2014-01-02 |   11 |        1 |
| 2014-01-02 |   12 |        1 |
| 2014-01-02 |   13 |        1 |
| 2014-01-02 |   14 |        1 |
| 2014-01-02 |   15 |        1 |
| 2014-01-02 |   16 |        1 |
| 2014-01-02 |   17 |        1 |
| 2014-01-02 |   18 |        1 |
| 2014-01-02 |   19 |        1 |
| 2014-01-02 |   20 |        1 |
| 2014-01-02 |   21 |        1 |
| 2014-01-02 |   22 |        1 |
| 2014-01-02 |   23 |        1 |
| 2014-01-03 |    0 |        1 |
| 2014-01-03 |    1 |        1 |
| 2014-01-03 |    2 |        1 |
| 2014-01-03 |    3 |        1 |
| 2014-01-03 |    4 |        1 |
```

Of course you'd have to adjust the helping table. It surely is not a bad thing such helping tables around.

Again, here's a <kbd>[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e7c056/10/0)</kbd> to see it working live.

---

**Original answer:**

```
select date(a), hour(a), count(*)
from (
    select enter as a from t
    union all
    select `exit` as a from t
) b
group by 1, 2
```

- see it working live in an <kbd>[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5eb198/3/0)</kbd>

Note though, that there are certain assumptions.

1. The times always are to a full hour
2. Enter and Exit date are always on the same day
3. Enter and exit times only differ in one hour

If one of these assumptions is not true, it gets a lot more complex

Comment: That's great if they are only an hour apart...I wonder If OP knows his example they are all one hour, and if this is a standard..

Comment: @Hituptony I know that and mentioned it in my answer. People get what they describe in their question :) A good way in my opinion to learn not only how to ask, but also what to look out for when analyzing problems. And therefore also which cases sample data needs to consider.

Comment: I am an analyst, and as an analyst one of my rules is - never assume. haha...I totally agree with all your comments. :)

Comment: Hello, no the hours are not one hours apart, they could be as granular as seconds.

Comment: I can set the database to only contain hours and not minutes, however, a person can enter and exit even after two days or three. How would it look like then?

Comment: @LeRay Adjusted my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort and response, I really appreciate all the help. Quick question, I'm planning to do this on a month to month base, so I'll have to generate a helper table for each month? 30 days (24 entries per day?)

Comment: @LeRay How about you create one table for dates and one table for every hour. Then you join both tables. You can make the dates table span a really big time range, it doesn't hurt (doesn't take much space, is performant and above all it's helpful). Create this once and you're done. :) And the usual way to say thanks on SO is to upvote and accept the answer ;)

Comment: Hello. I have chose your answer and upvoted it. Can you elaborate a little more on the dates and hours? I have little to no experience with MySQL databases. Im planning to do this one a monthly basis.

Comment: Ah, sorry, wrong thought. This makes it too complicated, you can't join then simply when there are entries where enter and exit date differ in more than one day. Keep it simple in one table like in my answer. Not much difference. Just create a table big enough, you can even drop the id column and make the datetime column the primary key and you'll never have performance problems. You can do this like this: `alter table n drop column a, add primary key (b);` in the sqlfiddle I provided.

Comment: Ill look into it, for some reason the sqlfiddle is just stuck on "loading"